# I want to use phone number it should have 15 numeric digit and only two hyphen

Tags: regex

I want to use phone number it should have 15 numeric digit and only two hyphen.
I am using this but it is not working properly:

```
[\d\-]{7,15}
```

Comment: there should be groups of a certain size shouldn't there? "--111111111111111" isn't valid, or is it? Please provide an example phone number.

Comment: Your current regular expression has nothing to do with your requirements. It says that the string should have 7 to 15 characters, each of which should be a digit or a hyphen

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, only a digit or a hyphen. The fact that he escaped the hyphen while he didn't need to doesn't mean it's become "a backslash and a hyphen". But I still agree that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Loamhoof: Indeed, thanks. Removed that part from my comment.

Comment: @sp00m what ``? Didn't you just look at the stackoverflow code..?

Comment: @Loamhoof Try to put a single backslash in the `code format`...

Comment: I hate these “validate a telephone number” problems; the problem's always _actually_ much harder than people think it is (unless they're being lame and only wanting to handle numbers from one specific country).

Answer (score 2):

A phone number (that contains two hyphens) consists of three groups of numbers. Let's assume 3 groups of 5 numbers like so.

```
xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```

The natural regex for this is

```
^\d{5}-\d{5}-\d{5}$
```

To change the groups change the numbers is curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?=(.*?-){,2})[\d-]{7,15}$
```

This allows input 7-15 digits/dashes, but at most 2 dashes

Note that you don't have to escape a dash when it's first it last within a character class.